# Curious to know How curious I am

Tags: support, badges, profile-page

While seeing [my profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3282633/sulthan-allaudeen?tab=topactivity) today, I was still wondering how it can be 6 out 5.

[image]

Above is my Profile's `Next Badge` area which states 6/5 days asked.

After 5/5 Questions I should be awarded with the [Curious Badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4127/curious). But, Why I am still not awarded

Answer (score 12):

See below that the "x" that says "need positive question record."

From the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> A positive question record means you don't have too many closed, downvoted or deleted questions, overall. The formula is `(total questions - negative questions - closed - deleted)/total questions >= 0.5`. Questions that have been downvoted *and* closed *and* deleted count three times in this calculation!

You have quite a few deleted and negatively scored questions, which is making you ineligible for the badge. Your formula comes out to:

```
(15 - 5 - 3 - 7) / 15 = 0.0
```

Which is well below the 0.5 threshold for having a positive question record.

Comment: Oh, that's curious! I have no negative, no closed and no deleted questions and I'm not Curious :(

Comment: I have only three downvoted and same closed and same deleted questions. Does the same questions downvoted, closed and deteted question comes in when i get about curious?

Comment: @animuson♦️ Can you please respond?