# Why is the badge not awarded

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Why is the curious badge not awarded despite the fact that it shows 5/5 questions asked. Based on the image it shows I have asked 5 well received questions; but still it shows that is the next badge recommendation. So does it require a 6th well received question to get the badge?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I think this meta question will be helpfull, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302070/curious-to-know-how-curious-i-am

Comment: ok the link answers the question.. thanks @Thaillie :)

Answer (score 4):

The badge has two requirements - click on the badge and you will see that the "positive question record" requirement has not been met.

[image]

Comment: If the positive question record was never met why does it show 5/5? isnt that stupid? i know if i just ask 5 questions on 5 different dates it will not be 5/5.

Comment: @Vini - it shows that you have asked well-received questions on 5 separate days. That part of the badge requirements has been met and is correct.